Animation-Delay in Infinite Loop aren't consistent
I've created a hover effect for containers via css animations. It's not so much about the color change, as the final solution is to switch images instead of divs.
The loop works, but the timings don't work as expected in some cases.
The delay from last to first element is a bit longer, from first to second element is too short, after the loop has run through once. The more childs the container has, the more confusing the loop gets. In the 4th container, the first one doesn't show up again.


body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  --collection-timing: 0.5s;
}

body>div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation-name: slideshow;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

div div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: var(--collection-timing);
  z-index: 2 !important;
}

div div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 2);
}

div div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 3);
}

div div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 4);
}

div div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 5);
}

div div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 6);
}

div div:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 7);
}

div div:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 8);
}

div div:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 9);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(1)) div {
  animation-duration: var(--collection-timing);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(2)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 2);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(3)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 3);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(4)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 4);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(5)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 5);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(6)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 6);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(7)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 7);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(8)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 8);
}

div:has(div:nth-child(9)) div {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--collection-timing) * 9);
}
div div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
div div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

div div:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}

div div:nth-child(4) {
  background: yellow;
}

div div:nth-child(5) {
  background: greenyellow;
}

div div:nth-child(6) {
  background: orange;
}

div div:nth-child(7) {
  background: grey;
}

div div:nth-child(8) {
  background: plum;
}

body>div:hover div {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

body>div:not(:hover) div {
  z-index: -1 !important;
}

body>div:not(:hover) div:first-child {
  z-index: 2 !important;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>


<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>




Is there a particular reason why you don't use keyframe for color changes? If you provide the same animation as above, is it okay if it's a lot different from the current code?

@NINE Yes. In the final version, there will be images instead of simple divs.

@NINE There is no problem about a totally different solution, if it's pure css and working with images, instead of divs, as well.

Your calculation for animation delay is wrong. It needs to multiply by (n-1) not n because when n is one you are delaying the start of the animation, but actually you want it to start straight away on the hover.

@AHaworth After the first loop, the first element wouldn't show up again. The problem is the switch from the last element to the first one, or even switching from last to second element (last box).

I wasn’t implying my comment described a complete solution, only that it is part of your problem.

A much simpler, and more general solution, can be found with a couple of lines of JavaScript. Is JS acceptable?

I really don't like using JS for such simple animations. There needs to be a reason, why the timings are buggy.

The CSS isn't very simple if you need a general case (as many or as few images as you like). I will put up a general solution in JS which is much less wordy in case it is of use to future readers.

@AHaworth What's not simple about the css? I could do a JS solution as well. But go ahead, maybe someone is happy to have one.

The problem with the CSS is having to have explicitly spelled out settings for each number of images - your code has (almost) gone to 9 images, but what if you wanted 20 - you'd have to add all those settings. With the JS you just add the images to the DOM and everything works OK, no calculations or extra CSS.

@AHaworth Surely inconvenient for other use cases, but the buggy output still doesn't make sense to me.

OK, I see you want an explanation of the timing/disappearing element problem rather than alternative methods. It's an interesting problem. For a start, try changing the animation-duration times - they do not have the effect I suspect you were expecting. In fact, the animation keyframes are probably not having the expected effect - how long would you expect an element to be at the final z-index: 1 value?

@AHaworth I set it to half a second so that the effect is more visible. No matter what delay you use, the problem persists. Unless I'm missing something in my code, it must be a browser/css-bug. Number of childs * delay = total duration. While the first example works as expected, there is no logical reason why the delay doesn't work for the variants with more children.

The delay may be there, but think through exactly what is happening. For how long does one of those divs have a z-index less than 2? I think we see a sort of 'OK' result with a few divs because the system just about manages to repaint in the gaps - however, try lengthening the time of each animation - you'll find there is no difference.

You can achieve same effect with @keyframes as mentioned by @NINE. Just need to add different background images at different percentage.
I have created example with two images but you can use more images. Below is working example.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .mainDiv {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #1e1e1e;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .sampleImg {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/16534745/pexels-photo-16534745/free-photo-of-pavilions-on-gadisar-lake.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
            background-size: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            animation: 3s changeImg infinite;
        }

        @keyframes changeImg {
            0% {
                background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/16534745/pexels-photo-16534745/free-photo-of-pavilions-on-gadisar-lake.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
            }

            50% {
                background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/20074914/pexels-photo-20074914/free-photo-of-forest.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
            }

            100% {
                background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/16534745/pexels-photo-16534745/free-photo-of-pavilions-on-gadisar-lake.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");

            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="sampleImg"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>




This does not solve the problem at all, and it is an inconvenient solution to add a flexible number of images in css, while you can simply have images in html.

@Fantasterei then you should not add this in comment "There is no problem about a totally different solution, if it's pure css and working with images"

@Fantasterei could you spell out what are the actual constraints that you have - you did ask for  a pure CSS solution, and this is one (albeit you'd need different keyframes for different numbers of images) but now you are saying you want an HTML/CSS solution - is that right and if so what are the constraints? (I still advocate a two line JS solution!).

The problem with the solution of @Meet is, it isn't that flexible without auto-generating a big css file with hundreds of images. I don't see why nobody addressed the issue with the code above. Do you guys know why the animation is buggy?

@Fantasterei Your provided css in question is also going to be large css as you have to add images to card somehow, either with css or html or js. You seems more unclear about what you want then us but still if you have lot images then solution from "Haworth" with js will be best for flexibility and you are right this isn't that flexible without auto-generating a big css file with hundreds of images.

@Meet It's two kilobytes, against hundreds of image-paths and keyframes. I know exactly what I want and for my solution, there is no problem with limiting to a few childrens. No one was able to address the bug itself.

I realise the OP requires a CSS solution, but that can get very unweildy if it's to cover a lot of cases (in terms of number of images) so I put this JS here in case of use to other readers.
The trick here is to use JS prepend on the last element in the list - takes it off the end and puts it at the beginning (or you could do the reverse using append if you want a different order).
This means there is no need to do any calculation on number of images or on timing related to that. Each image simply stays at the top of the pile (ie is the one shown) for whatever time is required without needing to calculate timings.


let interval = '';
const parent = document.querySelector('body>div');
parent.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    parent.prepend(parent.lastElementChild);
  }, 2000);
});
parent.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
body>div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body>div>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
<body>
  <h2>FOUR IMAGES</h2>
  <div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/200"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/200"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/200"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1020/200/200"></div>
  </div>
</body>





let interval = '';
const parent = document.querySelector('body>div');
parent.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    parent.prepend(parent.lastElementChild);
  }, 2000);
});
parent.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
body>div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body>div>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
<h1>SEVEN IMAGES</h1>
<div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1020/200/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1021/200/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1022/200/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1023/200/200"></div>
</div>

</body>



